# await void Task(C#)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need to run some useful code after run an empty task before await for it finish.

sample:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task t = SomeAsync();
    MessageBox.Show("before end");
    await t; // <-- how to write this?
    MessageBox.Show("after end");
}

private async Task SomeAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do some work;
    });
}
```

I know how to write this on tasks but can't understand async/await. Can anyone write working sampe.

Thanks.

Comment: If `Button_Click` was declared as `async`, then it should work; but you could also do `var result = await SomeAsync()`

Comment: @jpaugh I can't do that, becouse I want do some work (MessageBox.Show("before end"); in example) before waiting for task end. Answer below is working as I want.

Comment: The answer below does exactly what I mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare the handler as `async`

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task t = SomeAsync();
    MessageBox.Show("before end");
    await t; 
    MessageBox.Show("after end");
}
```

You should consider surrounding `await t` with a `try.. catch` as unhandled errors in `t` will bubble up as application un handled exceptions and bring down you application. You can handle all unobserved `Task` exceptions using [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) but you should read the documentation to see if this is suitable for your application.